# Laravel livewire adding checkbox dynamically

Tags: laravel-blade, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

so i've been learning livewire for a few days
i'm trying to make a checkbox added dynamically to livewire component.
i already can adding the new checkbox each time i click the plus button
but the problem is occured when i'm trying to click the added checkbox
like on the screenshot when i try to click the 3rd checkbox, its being clicked for 1 second but then the clicked move to checkbox 1
and when i click again the 2nd checkbox is clicked
after the 3rd click then the 3rd checkbox clicked
it will happen to all the added checkbox

[Here is the form screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iddH.png)

here is my code

addTodo.blade.php

```html
<div x-data="{ modalOpen : false }" x-cloak >
    <div class="group text-center cursor-pointer fixed bottom-0 right-0 mb-4 mr-4 flex items-center content-center overflow-y-auto">
        <div class="group-hover:opacity-100 transition-all ease-in-out duration-300 opacity-0 p-2 mr-3 bg-white rounded text-sm">Add New Todo</div>
        <button @click="modalOpen = true" class="m-auto w-12 h-12 bg-blue-500 rounded-full shadow-lg text-lg text-white text-center">
            <svg class="mx-auto"  width="32px" height="32px" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-plus" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v3h3a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-3v3a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-3h-3a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h3v-3A.5.5 0 0 1 8 4z"/>
            </svg>
        </button>
    </div>

    <div x-show.immediate.transition.opacity="modalOpen"  class="modal--wrapper bg-black flex items-center content-center bg-opacity-50 fixed top-0 left-0 w-full h-full">

        <div  @click.away="modalOpen = false" class="modal w-1/2 shadow-lg relative bg-white rounded mx-auto ">
            <div class="modal__header flex items-center py-4 bg-blue-500 text-white px-8 rounded-tr rounded-tl">
                <span>Add new Todo</span>
                <div @click="modalOpen = false" class=" ml-auto text-white text-3xl cursor-pointer">
                    &times;
                </div>
            </div>
            <form wire:submit.prevent="addtodo">
                <div class="modal__body mt-8 px-8">
                    <div class="flex flex-col">
                        <input type="text" wire:model="title" placeholder="Todo name" class="border-2 outline-none focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 flex-1 block w-full rounded px-4 py-2 sm:text-sm border-gray-300" />
                    @error('title')
                        <span class="text-sm text-red-500 mt-1">{{$message}}</span>
                    @enderror
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex flex-col mt-3">
                        <textarea wire:model="description" placeholder="Todo description" class="border-2 outline-none focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 flex-1 block w-full rounded px-4 py-2 sm:text-sm border-gray-300"></textarea>
                    </div>

                    <div class="flex flex-col">
                        <div class="mt-3 flex items-center ">
                            <input type="text" wire:model="task.0" class="border-2 flex-1 outline-none focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500  rounded px-4 py-2 sm:text-sm border-gray-300" placeholder="Task description" />
                            <div class="flex items-start ml-3">
                                <div class="flex items-center h-5">

                                        <label  class="text-sm ml-1 font-medium  cursor-pointer text-gray-700">
                                            <input
                                            wire:key="0"
                                            wire:model="is_done.0"
                                            id="isdone0"
                                            type="checkbox"
                                            class="focus:ring-blue-500 h-4 w-4  cursor-pointer text-blue-600 border-gray-300 rounded">
                                            Is done
                                        </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <button type="button" wire:click.prevent="add_task({{$add_index}})" class=" ml-3 focus:ring-blue-900 rounded  bg-blue-500 text-white hover:bg-blue-600">
                                <svg class="mx-auto"  width="24px" height="24px" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-plus" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v3h3a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-3v3a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-3h-3a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h3v-3A.5.5 0 0 1 8 4z"/>
                                </svg>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        @error('task.0')
                            <span class="text-sm text-red-500 mt-1">{{$message}}</span>
                        @enderror
                    </div>


                    @foreach($task_input as $key => $task)
                        <div class="mt-3 flex items-center ">
                            <input type="text" wire:model="task.{{$task}}" class="border-2 flex-1 outline-none focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500  rounded px-4 py-2 sm:text-sm border-gray-300" placeholder="Task description" />
                            <div class="flex items-start ml-3">
                                <div class="flex items-center h-5">

                                    <label
                                        wire:key="{{$task}}"
                                        class="ml-1 text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">
                                            <input
                                            wire:key="{{$task}}"
                                            wire:model="is_done.{{$task}}"
                                            id="isdone{{$task}}"
                                            type="checkbox"
                                            class="focus:ring-blue-500 h-4 w-4 text-blue-600 border-gray-300 rounded">
                                            Is done
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <button type="button" wire:click.prevent="remove_task({{$key}})" class="ml-3 text-red-500 cursor-pointer">
                                <svg width="24px" height="24px" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-trash" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                    <path d="M5.5 5.5A.5.5 0 0 1 6 6v6a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V6a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5zm2.5 0a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v6a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V6a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5zm3 .5a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v6a.5.5 0 0 0 1 0V6z"/>
                                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M14.5 3a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H13v9a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H5a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V4h-.5a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V2a1 1 0 0 1 1-1H6a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 1 1h3.5a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v1zM4.118 4L4 4.059V13a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h6a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V4.059L11.882 4H4.118zM2.5 3V2h11v1h-11z"/>
                                </svg>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="flex flex-col">
                            @error('task.*')
                                <span class="text-sm text-red-500 mt-1">{{$message}}</span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
                    @endforeach
                </div>
                <div class="modal__footer mt-5 pt-4 pb-8 px-8">
                    <button type="submit" class="bg-blue-500 text-white px-3 py-2 rounded hover:bg-blue-600">Add Todo</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

addTodo.php

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Todo;

use App\Models\Todo;
use App\Models\TodoItem;
use Livewire\Component;

class Addtodo extends Component
{
    public $title, $description;
    public $task, $is_done;
    public $task_input = [];
    public $add_index = 0;

    protected $rules = [
        'title' => 'required',
        'description' => 'nullable',
        'task.0' => 'required',
        'is_done.0' => 'nullable',
        'task.*' => 'required',
        'is_done.*' => 'nullable'
    ];

    protected $messages = [
        'task.0.required' => 'The task description field is required',
        'task.*' => 'The task description field is required',
    ];

    public function remove_task($i)
    {
        unset($this->task_input[$i]);
    }
    public function add_task($add_index)
    {
        $add_index = $add_index + 1;
        $this->add_index = $add_index;
        array_push($this->task_input, $add_index);
    }
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.todo.addtodo');
    }
    public function addtodo()
    {
        $this->validate();
        $todo = new Todo();
        $todo->title = $this->title;
        $todo->description = ($this->description == null) ? "" : $this->description;
        $todo->creator = 1;
        $result = $todo->save();

        foreach ($this->task as $key => $task) {
            $todo_item  = new TodoItem();
            $todo_item->description = $task;
            $todo_item->is_done = ($this->is_done == null) ? false : $this->is_done[$key];
            $todo_item->todo_id = $todo->id;
            $todo_item->save();
        }

        $this->reset_fields();
        $this->emit('todoAdded');
    }

    public function reset_fields()
    {
        $this->title = "";
        $this->description = "";
        $this->task = [];
        $this->is_done = [];
        $this->task_input = [];
        $this->add_index = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so this happen because i haven't set the initial value of the checkbox

i achieve the solutions simply by changing my code like this

```php
 public function add_task($add_index)
    {
        $add_index = $add_index + 1;
        $this->add_index = $add_index;
        $this->is_done[$add_index] = false;
        array_push($this->task_input, $add_index);      
    }
```